# DjangoSEO installation error - No module named hashcompat

Tags: python, django

I want to use DjangoSEO in my project.

I followed installation instructions provided in their [documentation](http://django-seo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction/tutorial.html):

1. I ran `pip install djangoseo` and then confirmed it with `pip freeze`
2. Added `rollyourown.seo` to my `INSTALLED_APPS` setting
3. Added `"django.core.context_processors.request"` to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting
4. When I try to run `python manage.py syncdb` or run my application I get the following error

> D:\Development\SpellCheck\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sites\models.py:78:
>   RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class django.contrib.sites.models.Site
>   doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an
>   application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its
>   application was loaded. This will no longer be supported in Django
>   1.9.   class Site(models.Model):
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:/Development/SpellCheck/manage.py", line 10, in 
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "D:\Development\SpellCheck\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 338, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "D:\Development\SpellCheck\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 312, in execute
>       django.setup()   File "D:\Development\SpellCheck\venv\lib\site-packages\django__init__.py",
>   line 18, in setup
>       apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "D:\Development\SpellCheck\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py",
>   line 85, in populate
>       app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)   File "D:\Development\SpellCheck\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py",
>   line 119, in create
>       import_module(entry)   File "C:\Python27\Lib\importlib__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
>       **import**(name)   File "D:\Development\SpellCheck\venv\lib\site-packages\rollyourown\seo__init__.py",
>   line 4, in 
>       from rollyourown.seo.base import Metadata, Tag, KeywordTag, MetaTag, Raw, Literal, get_metadata, get_linked_metadata   File
>   "D:\Development\SpellCheck\venv\lib\site-packages\rollyourown\seo\base.py",
>   line 17, in 
>       from django.utils.hashcompat import md5_constructor ImportError: No module named hashcompat

My seo.py looks like this:

```
from rollyourown import seo


class MyMetadata(seo.Metadata):
    title = seo.Tag(head=True, max_length=68)
    description = seo.MetaTag(max_length=155)
    keywords = seo.KeywordTag()
    heading = seo.Tag(name="h1")
```

Any ideas on what I have done wrong?